# Quantum gates defined in SpinQ desktop computers

Tags: quantum-gate

There is manufacturer of desktop quantum computers:
https://www.spinquanta.com/products.

There are few models on the market:

- Gemini
- Gemini-Mini
- Triangulum
- Lyra

Does anyone know where to find quantum gates list and their definitions for those computers?

Update: 
I have got information from several resources: 
Gemini/Gemini-Mini:

- CNOT
- CNOTx
- CNOTy
- CNOTz
- H
- RX(theta)
- RY(theta)
- RZ(theta)
- X
- X90 / RX(π/2)
- Y
- Y90 / RY(π/2)
- Z
- Z90 / RZ(π/2)

Triangulum:

- CCZ
- CNOTx
- CNOTy
- CNOTz
- H
- I
- RX(theta)
- RY(theta)
- RZ(theta)
- S
- S-dagger
- T
- T-dagger
- TOFFOLI
- X
- X90 / RX(π/2)
- Y
- Y90 / RY(π/2)
- Z
- Z90 / RZ(π/2)

For the Lyra (superconducting chip quantum computer) gates are the same as IBM's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gemini, Gemini-Mini, and Triangulum are NMR systems whose available quantum gates are; as [SpinQ Triangulum: a commercial three-qubit desktop quantum computer](https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.02983) says:

> The single-qubit gates are Pauli gates ($σ_{x}$, $σ_{y}$ , $σ_{z}$ ), 90 degree rotation gates and arbitrary rotation gates along `x`, `y` and `z` axes, Hadamard gates, `T` gates and inverse of `T` gates. The two-qubit gates are `CNOT` and `CZ` gates between any pairs of the three qubits. The three-qubit gates are the `Toffoli` gates with any two of the three qubits as the control qubits, and the `CCZ` gates which implement a
> `π` phase change to $|111\rangle$.

Lyra is a superconduting quantum computer. A fruitless search of their native gateset motivated me to pen an email:[image]

Let's wait for a response.

**Update**: Got back a response. For the Lyra, it's superconducting chip quantum computers, and the gates are the same as IBM's. I've attached images for the gatesets of Gemini and Trianulum

[image: Gemini Gateset]

[image: Trianulum Gateset]